Suggestion regarding questions with answers not marked as answered
This has been something that has popped into my mind several times over the years. It happened again yesterday regarding this question.
My suggestion is to consider adding the functionality to flag questions that have answers that should be accepted. If a flag is raised, it could be added to a review queue for other members to vote on whether or not the question has indeed been answered, the same way we vote to close questions for being too basic, etc.
I believe the linked question above has an answer and should be marked as such. I realize it has only been a day, and I don't know if the OP has seen the answer, but it should be accepted at some point. So, there would need to be some way of giving the OP a chance to view and accept their answer before allowing the community to jump on them and do it for them, but If I dig through the site, hundreds of questions have decent answers that should be accepted yet aren't accepted.
If this happens to be viewed as a poor suggestion, does anyone have any other ideas?
I believe it would improve the ability of someone to search the site and not ask a duplicate question. Some questions get marked as duplicates (rightfully so) and then point to a question with a good answer, yet it isn't accepted. Perhaps, the duplicate was asked because the OP found the duplicate question and wasn't confident that the answer was decent due to it not being marked as an accepted answer. Or, perhaps I'm reaching here in this last paragraph to justify my suggestion...thoughts?

I like your idea, a lot but I don't think it will be realized by StackExchange the company. Apparently this is by design as explained in this answer.

Thanks for this. While I understand and agree with the answer to an extent, it doesn't fit well for all forums under the Stack Exchange umbrella. What I mean is there are certain forums (such as Freelancers or Expatriates) where many answers can be opinions, and no one should be forced to accept someone else's opinion as an answer. On the other hand, some forums (such as QSE, Math, etc.) have scientific or mathematical answers that cannot be disputed and, thus, should be accepted. C'est la vie.

@amdopt consider reading the help center for What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?. Accepted answer in SE does not and never means that it's the best answer, but only an answer that helps the asker the most. On the other hand, Stack Exchange considers questions as "answered" if there is at least one answer having a score above 0 (thus, also eligible as a duplicate target).

@AndrewT. Within certain fields, there are correct answers that cannot be disputed. Correct answers that are, indeed, the best answer because there is no opinion within the answer, just math. Whether or not the asker understands this is exactly what my suggestion addresses. The community could be improved by correctly marking those answers as accepted.
I don't care about the existing semantics within the help center regarding what method SE uses to consider a question answered. The entire point of my post was that there is room for improvement.

I do not like the idea, as only the asker knows whether the answer was helpful for them. The answer may be technically correct but not understandable, or there may be other valid reasons for why the asker's concern has not been successfully addressed. Occasionally the asker may also be more knowledgeable about their question than many members of the community; their decision could be less well informed than the asker's. That is why we need the tick mark and why we have it.
We could introduce another tick mark to gauge community's approval if you are interested in that... Oh, but we do not need another tick mark – we have the ability to vote!
P.S. I have posted this answer despite another one having already been accepted ;)
